# Excel IF function with 3 or more conditions

Tags: excel, function, if-statement, vlookup

I have a group of sales reps across the country who earn bonus' if they hit a certain minimum of sales/hr; the thresholds they have to reach vary with the province they work in. I need to create an auto-populate formula that calculates their bonus based on their performance (in terms of sales/hr) and the thresholds in their province.

The data about sales are in Sheet 1, shown here:

[image: See here]

Column I is the "Bonus Amount" that I want the formula to fill.
Column J is the "Sales/hr".
Column K is the rep's name.
Column F is the province he is working in.

In another sheet I have the 3 bonus guidelines:

- for reps in Quebec, with 2 levels they could hit;
- for the rest of Canada, with 3 levels they could hit;
- and for a certain drug store (province is irrelevant in this one) with 3 levels they could hit.

Here is what the second sheet looks like:

[image: Image of the data used for the formula is here]

**WHAT I NEED**

I need to auto-populate the bonus amount earned in column I ("Bonus amount") of sheet 1, for the rep in column K.

For example, for the rep shown at line 2, his name is "Name 1", he sold 47$/hour (column J) and he works in the Quebec province (column F). This means I have to check the first table in sheet 2, which is for Quebec: the minimum performance to get the bonus is 110$/hr, and since for this rep it is lower (47$/hr), he doesn't get the bonus. If his performance had reached 110$/hr he would have got a bonus of 25$, and if he had hit 180$/hr he would have got a bonus of 50$.

What formula can I use to populate the bonus amount for a given rep in a given province? As well as a rep working at the "certain drug store"(think of it the same as another province) - I am not sure how to embed this,

Comment: I see -4 already - does this mean i am asking for the wrong formula? Someone help.

Comment: First, the question is not so clear. You are showing one sheet, but not the first one. You talk about K1 and L1, but what is there? **Show some data that are enough to do the job manually, then maybe someone will find a way to do it with a formula.** Remember that this is a site where you ask for help, and not to do the job for you, including figuring out what you haven't explained. And your last sentence in caps-lock sounded arrogant, as though you were *demanding* help, not *asking* for it. So, [edit] your question to show the missing info and probably someone will help.

Comment: See edited version

Comment: I've edited the question again, showing the new picture and adding an example. It's a pretty heavy edit, I hope you agree on it (otherwise, feel free to edit; it's your question after all!). But please do not remove the example, which is something that really helps understanding the question. Of course, if my interpretation of what you want is wrong, please correct it. That said, I'm not that good at Excel, and I think I have to stop here. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this formula in cell I2 of Sheet1.

```
=IF(F2="QC",IF(J2<Sheet2!$B$4,"no bonus",IF(J2<Sheet2!$B$5,Sheet2!$A$4,Sheet2!$A$5)),IF(J2<Sheet2!$E$4,"no bonus",IF(J2<Sheet2!$E$5,Sheet2!$D$4,IF(J2<Sheet2!$E$6, Sheet2!$D$5,Sheet2!$D$6))))
```

This formula decides the bonus to be given only for Qubec and non-Qubec. Since you did not mention anything about "certain drug store", I did not include that here. Try this and let me know if you need more information

Comment: Hi Gowtham, 
Thanks so much for responding. I've tried this formula but it's missing something - it shows up as #NAME?

Comment: got it ! never mind - the "sheet 2!" needed to be " 'sheet 2!' "

Comment: Mayo, Thats great !!

Comment: Could we include the "certain drug store"? it is a different column and it hasn't fit in nicely... how can I add that section in as it is a different condition?

Comment: Mayo How will you find if it is a "certain drug store" based on province? Please let me know the step by step algorithm for drug store. I can work on that for you

Comment: Hi Gowtham, Thanks for reaching out - Just name the drug store as "rexall" so in another column there is a list of drug stores (realizing now that i did not include in the picture) LETS JUST ASSUME the column for "drug stores" is now column G on sheet 1. The other sheet is still the same...